# How to create column lines in a div table

Tags: html, css

I have a created a table with divs and I want to see lines down the sides of each column that extend all the way to the bottom. Right now they only extend down to the bottom of each list.
Here is what I have.

```css
.maCol {
        float: left;
        width: 10em;
        border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
        border-left: 1px solid #CCC;
        border-top: 0px;
        border-bottom: 0px;
    }
.maRow {
        /*border: 1px solid #DDD;*/
        padding: 0.5em;
    }
.maTable {
        border: 1px solid #CCC;
        float: left;
        border-radius: 6px;
    }
```

```html
<div id="marketAccessTableView" class="maTable">

    <div class="maCol L1">
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN1</label></div>
    </div>
    <div class="maCol L2">
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN2</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN2</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN2</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN2</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN2</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN2</label></div>
    </div>
    <div class="maCol L7">
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN3</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN3</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN3</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN3</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN3</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN3</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN3</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN3</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN3</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN3</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN3</label></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Redo your html It's extremely wrong

Comment: redo to what, please help?

Comment: "I have a created a table with divs " why not just use a table then? When it is tabular content, it is easier anyway.

Comment: Couple of the obvious ones. Rows should contain cols and labels don't wrap inputs, they are `for` inputs.

Comment: You shouldn't be putting your input inside your label. Indeed, labels exist for a reason: when specifying a for attribute which is equal to an input's id, clicking on the label will do exactly the same as if the user would have clicked on the input.

Answer (score 1):

Add `display:table;` to `.maTable` and `display:table-cell;` to `.maCol`. Remove `float:left;` from `.maCol`.

```css
.maCol {
        /*removed float:left;*/
        width: 10em;
        border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
        border-left: 1px solid #CCC;
        border-top: 0px;
        border-bottom: 0px;
        display:table-cell; /* add this */
    }
.maRow {
        /*border: 1px solid #DDD;*/
        padding: 0.5em;
    }
.maTable {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 6px;
    display: table; /* add this */
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="marketAccessTableView" class="maTable">

    <div class="maCol L1">
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN1</label></div>
    </div>
    <div class="maCol L2">
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN2</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN2</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN2</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN2</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN2</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN2</label></div>
    </div>
    <div class="maCol L7">
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN3</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN3</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN3</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN3</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN3</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN3</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN3</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN3</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN3</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN3</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN3</label></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is not ideal for what you are trying to achieve.

First of all, your columns are not set to a specific height, therefore they will inherit a height based on what content is inside them. That is why your first column is shorter than the second, and so forth.

Secondly, Setting a border-right on the columns adds a double border because you also set a border on the whole wrapper.

Thirdly, your labels should not wrap anything. That's what the `for` attribute is for.

Comment: please provide a solution in code for me to understand what to change. thanks!

Comment: Dasbeasto provided the code for you. The reason I didn't is because you wouldn't learn anything from a direct copy/paste. Rather, you should read my answer and understand what you did wrong so that you can solve your own problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you just add a height to the table and then have a height of 100% on the col's then they will extend to the bottom of the table. But like others have said, just use a real table instead of divs.

```css
.maCol {
        float: left;
        width: 10em;
        border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
        border-left: 1px solid #CCC;
        border-top: 0px;
        border-bottom: 0px;
        height: 100%;   //Change here
    }
.maRow {
        /*border: 1px solid #DDD;*/
        padding: 0.5em;
    }
.maTable {
        border: 1px solid #CCC;
        float: left;
        border-radius: 6px;
        height: 400px;  //and here

    }
```

```html
<div id="marketAccessTableView" class="maTable">

    <div class="maCol L1">
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN1</label></div>
    </div>
    <div class="maCol L2">
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN2</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN2</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN2</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN2</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN2</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN2</label></div>
    </div>
    <div class="maCol L7">
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN3</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN3</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN3</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN3</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN3</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN3</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN3</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN3</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN3</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN3</label></div>
        <div class="maRow"><label><input type="checkbox" name="vehicle" value="Bike"> SGN3</label></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I like this idea but I don't want to set the height of the table to a fixed value. Sometimes the columns will be longer an shorter then others.